# How a Java client app. can "catch" (via JDBC) the result produced by a trigger procedure query?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, triggers, callback, resultset

I'm trying to understand how a java (client) application that communicates, through JDBC, with a pgSQL database (server) can "catch" the result produced by a query that will be fired (using a trigger) whenever a record is inserted into a table.

So, to clarify, via JDBC I install a trigger procedure prepared to execute a query whenever a record is inserted into a given database table, and from this query's execution will result an output (wrapped in a resultSet, I suppose). And my problem is that I have no idea how the client will be aware of those results, that are asynchronously produced.

I wonder if JDBC supports any "callback" mechanism able to catch the results produced by a query that is fired through a trigger procedure under the "INSERT INTO table" condition. And if there is no such "callback" mechanism, what is the best approach to achieve this result?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not that I know of.  Triggers run entirely within the context of the database server, without JDBC's knowledge.  It's very much a request/response idiom, not a two-way socket communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers can't return a resultset.

There's no way to send such a result to the JDBC driver.

There are a few dirty hacks you can use to get results from a trigger to the client, but they're all exactly that. Things like:

- `DECLARE` a cursor for the resultset, then send the cursor name as a `NOTIFY` payload, so the app can `FETCH ALL FROM <cursorname>`;
- Create a `TEMPORARY` table and report the name via `NOTIFY`

It is more typical to append anything the trigger needs to communicate to the app to a table that exists for that purpose and have the app `SELECT` from it after the operation that fired the trigger ran.

In most cases if you need to do this, you're probably using a trigger where a regular function is a better fit.

Comment: So, to make it clear, there is no "standard" (no workaround) mechanism that a pgSQL database may use to notify a client app (written in java) about a "something" that may occur in the database schema, right? The database and their clients can only communicate through the client-server paradigm, being impossible for the database to push events back for their clients, right? And the clients are always responsible to *poll* database in order be aware about what is happening with their data.

Comment: @DiogoAnjos That's exactly what `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` are for. They aren't SQL-standard, but they're commonly used in PostgreSQL. That's why I mention `NOTIFY` above. There's support for receiving notifications in PgJDBC. See http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/listennotify.html .

Comment: Note for PostgreSQL LISTEN and NOTIFY on the provided link: "A key limitation of the JDBC driver is that it cannot receive asynchronous notifications and must poll the backend to check if any notifications were issued." So it is also polling, no push mechanism introduced here. :(

Comment: @MGM Kind-of. If you're not using SSL, PgJDBC can avoid polling. It still has to do a nonblocking socket read, but doesn't need to do a client/server round-trip.